# Dynamics NAV: Show date in text field according to regional settings

Tags: date, textfield, nav, microsoft-dynamics, regional-settings

I have a textfield that shows a date value - this needs to be a textfield because it also needs to show the value 'Undetermined' if the date value = 0D.

I would like to present the date in this text field according to my regional settings.

So for example, if my short date value from the regional settings is set to d/M/yyyy, I want the textfield to show 1/1/2015, and not 01/01/2015.

Does anyone knows if this is possible and HOW :)?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using [delChr Function (Code, Text)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354973.aspx) 
and delete the "0" on your TEXT

Comment: 'according to my regional setting'.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using DotNet variables.
You need to declare 3 DotNet variables and assign each the correct subtype, plus a variable, type 'Record', subtype 'Language'. Below you can see for each DotNet variable wich subtype you need to assign.

**Name:** CultureInfo
**DataType:** DotNet
**Subtype:** System.Globalization.CultureInfo.'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

**Name:** DateTimeFormatInfo
**DataType:** DotNet
**Subtype:** System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

**Name:** DateTime1
**DataType:** DotNet
**Subtype:** System.DateTime.'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

```
Date2Text(Date : Date) : Text
CultureInfo           := CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Lng.GetLanguageID(Lng.GetUserLanguage));
DateTimeFormatInfo    := CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
DateTime1             := DateTime1.DateTime(DATE2DMY(Date,3), DATE2DMY(Date,2), DATE2DMY(Date,1));

EXIT(DateTime1.ToString('d', DateTimeFormatInfo));
```